# Similarity of two functions if their divergence and curl is the same.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I've been given the below equations $$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{D}=\rho_{\rm f} \:\:\:{\rm and}\:\:\: \boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{D}=0$$

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}_{\rm vac}=\frac{\rho_{\rm f}}{\epsilon_{0}} \:\:\:{\rm and}\:\:\: \boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{E}_{\rm vac}=0$$

Where both of the functions $D$ and $E_{\text {vac }}$ go to zero at infinity.

Then how can one deduce from these equations the relation $\mathbf{D}=\epsilon_{0} \mathbf{E}_{\text {vac}}$ ,given that it's not necessary for two functions to be same if their divergence and curl is the same?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are thinking about these equations out of context. If $\rho = \rho_f + \rho_b\;\;$ (the charge distribution is the sum of the free and bound charges) then we can write the Gauss law as $$\epsilon_0\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}  = \rho = \rho_f + \rho_b \;.$$

Recall that the bound charge however relates to the polarization $\mathbf{P}$ as $$\rho_b = -\nabla \cdot \mathbf{P}$$

thus we can write

$$\epsilon_0\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}  = \rho_f -\nabla \cdot \mathbf{P}$$

$$\text{which implies that}$$

$$\epsilon_0\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{P}  = \rho_f$$

$$\text{and thus}$$

$$\nabla \cdot(\epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P})  = \rho_f \;\;.$$

We then define a new field which we call the electric displacement as $$\mathbf{D} \equiv \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P} \;.$$

It is very important to note that this is a definition and not a result. In the case where we are in a vacuum, there is no bound charge so the polarization field $\mathbf{P}$ is zero. This directly implies that $$\mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E}  \;.$$

$$ $$
$\textbf{EDIT:}$

To clear up some confusion regarding a comment below, $\mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} \;\;$ does $\mathbf{not}$ hold for linear dielectrics rather the equation

$$\mathbf{D} = \epsilon \mathbf{E}$$ holds instead where $\epsilon \equiv \epsilon_0(1 + \chi_e). $ Note that $\epsilon_0 $ is the permittivity of free space wheras $\epsilon$ is the permittivity of the medium in question. $\chi_e$ is known as the electric susceptibility of the medium and is zero in vacuum.

It can also be shown that $\mathbf{P} = \epsilon_0 \chi_e \mathbf{E}$. Observe that

$$\mathbf{D} \equiv \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P}  = \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} +\epsilon_0 \chi_e \mathbf{E}$$

$$\text{implying}$$

$$\mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0 (1+\chi_e)\mathbf{E} = \epsilon \mathbf{E} \;.$$

Comment: No $D= e_0E$ holds inside a dielectric as well. See Griffiths.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/583974/contradiction-in-calculating-electric-field-outside-of-a-dielectric-material-emb

Comment: @YasirSadiq I would have to disagree with your notion that $\mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E}$ holds in a dielectric. Please see my edit above for details.